# Instantiate web3 to work with the real Ethereum network

Tags: web3js, nodejs, web3-providers

I know how to instantiate web3 to work with a local test network:

```
var web3Instance =  new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
```

How do I change this code to connect to the real network?

Answer (score 1):

That is how you connect to a real network, with web3.

The difference, however, is that instead of connecting to a testrpc (or Parity or Geth) node running a local, private network exposing an RPC interface, that instead you connect to a client connected to one of the test networks (or mainnet).

In the case of using HttpProvider, just start your client with the necessary [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) interfaces exposed.

[The documentation on the Ethereum wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#json-rpc-endpoint) gives you examples for a number of different clients.

Comment: So my code is ready to work against the real network, even though the address is http://localhost:8545? I don't need to change anything?

Comment: Correct. Although, you might want to consider what happens if your user isn't running a node locally and exposing an RPC interface that way e.g. if they are looking at your Dapp through a browser with MetaMask. The usual [fallback pattern is this](https://github.com/truffle-box/webpack-box/blob/1869d6a01d82cdf2c44e4d17d4a8c02955489377/app/javascripts/app.js#L91).